# Android Java Youtube API v3.0 get video RTSP link

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I want to play youtube video on `Surface`, using `MediaPlayer`.
So, I should put there direct video link.
Problem is: How to get this link on Android device?

Link like this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID
Is no longer available. Probably because of old and deprecated [API v2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol).
But **[this](http://savefrom.net/)** web service somehow do the trick.
And result link works perfect. So it is still possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with this url

```
String ytInfoUrl="http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + youtubeID + "&eurl="
                + URLEncoder.encode("https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/" + youtubeID, "UTF-8");
```

Open this using a HttpGet extract the RTSP urls from that info response.

**edit**

You can use this link for extracting the RTSP links https://github.com/flipstudio/YouTubeExtractor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flipstudio/youtube/extractor/YouTubeExtractor.java

**edit**

A lot have been changed please use this project for proper extraction https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/blob/master/youtubeExtractor/src/main/java/at/huber/youtubeExtractor/YouTubeExtractor.java

Comment: what is your initial request it should look something like this
"http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=SqhV4ouGdPE&eurl=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.googleapis.com%2Fv%2FSqhV4ouGdPE"

Comment: Try that url on postman ..I am getting the response ..No errors

Comment: Yes, i've got this request. Thinking on "extracting" RTSP url.

Comment: did you extracted the RTSP urls .If not try this link also https://github.com/flipstudio/YouTubeExtractor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flipstudio/youtube/extractor/YouTubeExtractor.java

Comment: how did u manage to extract the RTSP URL from that response.how did you do the parsing?

Comment: @ParthDoshi split the response and search for "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"

Comment: Thanks man, i have used this class:
https://github.com/flipstudio/YouTubeExtractor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flipstudio/youtube/extractor/YouTubeExtractor.java 
You saved my day :D

Comment: How to use above YoutubeExtractor mentioned above. What arguments I have to pass for extracting , VideoId or url obtained from above mentioned url.

Comment: @Sushantkumar You have to extract videoId by yourself. There are plenty of ways to do it just search in stack.

Comment: @sunilsunny this yoututbe extractor not working with all video Id

Comment: @Sushantkumar Yes some of the id's are not supported .This links need to deciphered to get the RTSP link.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sunilsunny. I'd been cracking my head over this and only getting answers to use deprecated google data apis. Thank god this solution exists. :)

Comment: @sunilsunny even though onSuccess been called, all the URIs i get are null. why is that?

Comment: @sunilsunny. It's working. Is this project is safe and free to use?

Comment: @SUXA It's free and safe to use for sure, but we are extracting the RTSP urls through backdoor which might be aganist the Yotube policies..