# What should be done when Youtube isn't installed for when using "YouTube Data API"?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

This is a short question:

I'm using "[**YouTube Data API**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support)", and I've noticed that if the YouTube app isn't installed, all demos of the sample just show a dialog telling the user to install the app.

I'd like to have a different fallback, so that the video will still play.

I assume I can use WebView, but is there a better way? Maybe a VideoView ?

What's the best alternative, without any libraries (using just the framework) for when YouTube app isn't installed?

Comment: You should be able to play the video from the rtsp link you get from the API.

Comment: @Nanoc How? Using which API ?

Comment: With a VideoView and the Youtube API you are using...

Comment: @Nanoc As far as I know, VideoView doesn't support YouTube Urls. They are not direct links to video files. They have HTML content. About rtsp link, how do you get it?

Comment: Yeah, thats why i said rtsp link, you should take a look at the doc. maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606019/android-java-youtube-api-v3-0-get-video-rtsp-link

Comment: @Nanoc So it's not a part of the API... I thought I've missed something there (which can be easily true, as today is the first time I check the website). Do you know of a sample of how to do it?